# Having difficulty in vue.js with vue3-easy-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am using vue3-easy-data-table as a library for data table in my project.

[link to library at github](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

There i have a logic with item statuses, which i get from api. So if item status is like "waiting for shipment" i want, for example, to make a red row background, and if another status - make white row background.

In examples at documentation [link to library documentation](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) for this library i see that there is a prop **body-row-class-name** and a function **bodyRowClassNameFunction** which determines what style should be appended to row according to some condition and returns a style name (in the code block below)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <EasyDataTable
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      :header-item-class-name="headerItemClassNameFunction"
      :body-row-class-name="bodyRowClassNameFunction"
      :body-expand-row-class-name="bodyExpandRowClassNameFunction"
      :body-item-class-name="bodyItemClassNameFunction"
      no-hover
    >
      <template #expand="item">
        {{ item.name }} in {{ item.class }} got {{ item.score }}
      </template>
    </EasyDataTable>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { Header, Item, BodyRowClassNameFunction, HeaderItemClassNameFunction, BodyItemClassNameFunction} from "vue3-easy-data-table";

const bodyRowClassNameFunction: BodyRowClassNameFunction = (item: Item, rowNumber: number): string => {
  if (item.score < 60) return 'fail-row';
  return 'pass-row';
};

const bodyExpandRowClassNameFunction: BodyRowClassNameFunction = (item: Item, rowNumber: number): string => {
  return 'expand-row';
};

const bodyItemClassNameFunction: BodyItemClassNameFunction = (column: string, rowNumber: number): string => {
  if (column === 'score') return 'score-column';
  return '';
};

const headerItemClassNameFunction: HeaderItemClassNameFunction = (header: Header, columnNumber: number): string => {
  if (header.value === 'score') return 'score-column';
  return '';
};

const headers: Header[] = [
  { text: "Name", value: "name" },
  { text: "Class", value: "class" },
  { text: "Score", value: "score", sortable: true },
];

const items: Item[] = [
  {name: 'HC', class: 'class 1', score: 100},
  {name: 'Curry', class: 'class 2', score: 59},
  {name: 'James', class: 'class 3', score: 59},
  {name: 'Durant', class: 'class 3', score: 59},
];
</script>

<style>
.score-column {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.fail-row  {
  --easy-table-body-row-background-color: #f56c6c;
  --easy-table-body-row-font-color: #fff;
}
.pass-row  {
  --easy-table-body-row-background-color: #67c23a;
  --easy-table-body-row-font-color: #fff;
}
.expand-row {
  --easy-table-body-row-background-color: grey;
  --easy-table-body-row-font-color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

Maybe the problem is that this library examples is in typescript, but the project is not using it.

Could you please help if anything i can do to make it work without typescrypt?
Why documented prop is not working?

Tnank you!!!

In my code i am trying a more simpler example to understand why some props doesnt works... I am pointing a style directly in **body-row-class-name** prop, but it is not working.

[template block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVeGJ.png)

[imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPXvs.png)

[style block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlBKB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You lack import for necessary CSS.

Add the line below to the script tag or the starting point main.ts

```
import 'vue3-easy-data-table/dist/style.css';
```

Comment: Hello, @Emil! Thank you, but the import you mentioned is present. I edited the question and added an image with imports. It seems like the problem is elsewhere